# How to change activity state programatically?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, onresume, onpause

In a tabhost application;

when I change the activated tab, within tab 1 activity ; by running this code:

```
((TabActivity) getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(2);
```

Tab 2 shown correctly, but, tab 1 activity doesn't move to the "Paused" state and its onPause() method not called.

And again, when I want to switch back to the tab 1, its onResume() method not called (as we expect because of state had not changed before).

Why the state doesn't change? How can I solve this?

Comment: Why the state of your activity must be changed after tab was changed? State could be changed only by system.

Comment: Normally, when you click a tab, one activity enters into the paused state and another comes to the foreground. I think this is the normal and desired behaviour. But when I switch the tab by code, state doesn't change and I can't do what I want.

Comment: You should really consider using Fragments with ActionBar and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the fragment is not paused when the tabs are switched, because they are tied to the activity. From the docs:

> onPause(): fragment is no longer interacting with the user either because its activity is being paused or a fragment operation is modifying it in the activity.
>
> onResume(): makes the fragment interacting with the user (based on its containing activity being resumed).

Instead, you could use the ActionBar tabs, and have your activity implement TabListener

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}


@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}


@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```